# How do I simplify: $ \exp \left(-a \frac{\log x}{\log Q} \right) $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify: $\displaystyle \exp \left(-a \frac{\log x}{\log Q} \right) $ ?

I think it should be $ \exp \left( \log_Q x^{-a} \right) = x^{-a}$

Did I miss a constant anywhere?

---

Let me try another one::

$$ \exp \left(-a \frac{\log x}{\log Q} \right) 
= \exp \left( \frac{\log x}{\log Q} \right)^{-a}
= \exp \left( \log x \right)^{-a/ \log Q}
= x^{-a/ \log Q}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice:

- $$e^{\frac{a\ln(b)}{\ln(c)}}=b^{\frac{a}{\ln(c)}}$$
- $$x=y^{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)}}$$

So:

$$\exp\left(-a\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(Q)}\right)=x^{\frac{-a}{\ln(Q)}}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{a}{\ln(Q)}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[\ln(Q)]{x^a}}$$

---

Your last edit is right!

Comment: It only took 5 tries!  This is from a research paper :-) It's full of these weird notations.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. The property that you have tried to use is perhaps:

> $$\large a=b^{\log_ba}$$

But as you can see that this requires the base of the logarithm to be equal to the number to which the log is a power.

Since $e\not = Q$

Hence, $ \exp \left( \log_Q x^{-a} \right) \not = x^{-a}$

Moreover the expression $\exp \left( \log_Q x^{-a} \right)$ cannot be further simplified "in its literal sense".